# How to solve this integral since it has a endpoint singularity?

Tags: integration, singularity

I have this simple function but cant seem to have consensus about its cauchy value integral.

I have to integrate it from -1 to 1, and it has a strong singularity on -1. Having that in mind I cant integrate using cauchy method since the singularity is not inside the integration limits. I have tried many things, like quadpack, singularity subtraction, and other methods.

I am suspecting that the value for the integral is either 0 or 0.3217282.

Having in mind that simple techniques failed to resolve this integral what would you try to find the value of the integral ??

Funtion:
Integration from -1 to 1
$$
{- 0.0001421026278\,{\frac {\xi\, \left( -1+\xi \right) }{
 0.00625000000+ 0.006250000000\,\xi}}}
$$

This is what I got from wolphram alpha:

[not convergent integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqRlb.jpg)

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, the correct method is to set this up as a limit. Namely, integrate from $a$ to $1$, and take the limit as $a\to-1$.

Comment: @ThomasGrubb:  that is the correct method if the integral is convergent.  It doesn't work here because the integral is not.

Comment: does not work i get infinity if I set to integrate a to 1 and set to limit as a tends to infinity

Comment: Math software is giving me 0, how to prove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking out the constants, you are trying to evaluate $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac {\xi(\xi-1)}{\xi+1}d\xi$$  This has a logarithmic divergence at $\xi=-1$ and nothing in the numerator to cancel it.  There is no finite answer.

Comment: There might be something real I should get, this integral comes from a numerical method and the integral is either 0 or something around 0.3 because those are values that makes the simulation work. I want to prove why it is 0 or other value

Comment: As given the integral is negative infinity.  Maybe there is something in the problem that is supposed to prevent the divergence and the numeric errors have mixed in an unacceptable solution.

Comment: The integration exist, and is 0 or another value. Normally in the numerical problem the value calculated for this integral with negative infinity cancels with other equal value obtained by a positive infinity integration. So my program works setting it to 0 or trying to integrate with other techniques wich gives some random value, that cancels with the positive infinity integral obtaining 0 at the end. The question is: should i set it to zero ? How to obtain a real value from this integral...

Comment: Math software is giving me 0, how to prove it ?